# Using Union to create a temp table for similar tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've 5 tables that have similar Structure and similar Names like Subscriptions_123,Subscriptions_456 etc.

I need to create a temp table clubbing all these five tables data together based on a condition.

Right now I'm first creating a temp table and then inserting data into it.Is there a way to create the temp table (using this query)in the from clause of another query.

The query is

```
Select
       MOB_NO
     , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
     , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
  from Subscriptions 
 where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                             from CommonLookup 
                            where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
 UNION 
Select MOB_NO
     , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
     , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
  from Subscriptions_125
 where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                             from CommonLookup 
                            where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
 UNION 
Select MOB_NO
     , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
     , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
  from Subscriptions_467
 where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                             from CommonLookup 
                            where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
 UNION 
Select MOB_NO
     , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
     , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
  from Subscriptions_Campaign
 where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                             from CommonLookup 
                            where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
 UNION 
Select MOB_NO
     , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
     , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
  from Subscriptions_Kenan1
 where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                             from CommonLookup 
                            where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
```

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Why do you need to create a temp table? Why not simply a view?

Comment: Why not make them into one table in the first place?

Comment: Multiple tables with the same structure usually indicates a broken data model where part of what should be *data* in *column(s)* has instead ended up in the table *names*. You wouldn't (hopefully) create `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables.

Comment: But what is really the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH AllData AS (
    SELECT MOB_NO
          ,Subscription_Start_Date
          ,Unsubscribed_Date
          ,Subscription_Id
    FROM Subscriptions
  UNION ALL
    SELECT MOB_NO
          ,Subscription_Start_Date
          ,Unsubscribed_Date
          ,Subscription_Id
    FROM Subscriptions_125
  UNION ALL
    ...
)
,Filtered AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT -- Only needed if your tables can contain duplicates
           MOB_NO
          ,CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) AS SUB_DATE
          ,CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date) AS UNSUB_DATE 
    FROM AllTables
    WHERE SubscriptionId IN (SELECT ServiceID
                             FROM CommonLookup
                             WHERE ShortCode IN (816602,816603,816604))
)
SELECT * FROM Filtered
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use your select as a subselect for a select into and create a temp-table that way, for whatever reason:

```
select *
  into temp_table
  from (
        Select
               MOB_NO
             , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
             , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
          from Subscriptions 
         where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                                     from CommonLookup 
                                    where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
         UNION 
        Select MOB_NO
             , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
             , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
          from Subscriptions_125
         where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                                     from CommonLookup 
                                    where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
         UNION 
        Select MOB_NO
             , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
             , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
          from Subscriptions_467
         where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                                     from CommonLookup 
                                    where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
         UNION 
        Select MOB_NO
             , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
             , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
          from Subscriptions_Campaign
         where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                                     from CommonLookup 
                                    where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
         UNION 
        Select MOB_NO
             , CONVERT(DATE,Subscription_Start_Date) SUB_DATE
             , CONVERT(DATE,Unsubscribed_Date)       UNSUB_DATE 
          from Subscriptions_Kenan1
         where Subscription_Id in (select Distinct ServiceID 
                                     from CommonLookup 
                                    where ShortCode in (816602,816603,816604))
       ) isel
```